# fastest way to replace values in one df with values from another df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df1 that looks like this :

```
class     val
12        1271
12        1271
34        142
34        142
```

and another df2 that looks like this

```
class  val
12     123
34     141
69     667
```

What would be the fastest way to map CorrectVal to df1 such that the resultant df is :

```
class     val
12        123
12        123
34        141
34        141
```

Ideally I would join the 2 dfs with df.merge and drop the val field and rename CorrectVal with val like so

```
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'val':'correctVal'})
df_resultant=df1.merge(df2, how ='left' , on='class')
df_resultant.drop(columns='val').rename(columns={'CorrectVal':'val'})
```

but this might not be the fastest way, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution should be simlify with remove column `val` from `df1`:

```
df_resultant=df1.drop(columns='val').merge(df2, how ='left' , on='class')
```

Or use mapping by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), I guess this solution should be faster, best test in real data:

```
df_resultant = df1.assign(val= df1['class'].map(df2.set_index('class')['val']))
```

Comment: curious to know if this is the fastest way or if doing a df['col'].apply() is?

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami - I think `apply` are loops under the hood, so it is slowier. I guess faster should be map. Is possible test it in real your data?